# VBA only exports partial recordset

Tags: vba, database, function, ms-access, text

The following code is linked to my access database and exports one column from the table to a txt file, however, it randomly stops on a specific record and won't export the rest of the file:

```
Sub ExportTxtFiles()

    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
    
    Open "\\...Export Files\ZM.txt" For Output As #1
        
    Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tbl_temp", dbOpenSnapshot)
    
    If rst.RecordCount > 0 Then
        rst.MoveFirst
        Do Until rst.EOF
            Print #1, rst!ID
        rst.MoveNext
        Loop
    End If
    
    rst.Close
    
    Set rst = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

Table has 347 lines and stops halfway through the number in line 304.

Comment: In general `RecordCount` may not be reliable unless you've performed a `MoveLast` on the recordset.  Maybe you're not actually writing the file?  Try adding `Debug.Print rst.RecordCount` after opening the recordset and see what you get.

Answer (score 0):

You never close the file. Files are buffered, so VBA is free to wait for more to be planned to be written, and only write that when the buffer is full or the file is closed.

Close the file with the `Close` statement:

```
Close #1
```

However, I strongly recommend not relying on `Print` for files. Instead, use `DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim`, it's generally faster and `Print` has some quirks